# instantiating a module inside an always block

Tags: verilog

I am just starting to learn verilog, so this may be a very basic question, but i couldn't really understand or find an alternative to express my intentions in verilog.

I will take a smaller example. I am basically trying to connect the output of one of my modules to input for another. Please help me with line mark 49 and give an alternative to it.

```
   25 module ands (
   26     input1,
   27     input2,
   28     outputs
   29 );
   30     input [2:0] input1;
   31     input input2;
   32     output [2:0] outputs;
   33 
   34     integer itr;
   35 
   36     and a (outputs[0],input1[0],input2);
   37     initial
   38     begin
   39         for (itr = 1 ; itr <= 2; itr = itr+1)
   40             and a(outputs[itr],input1[itr],outputs[itr-1]);
   41     end
   42 
   43 endmodule
```

I know it is a stupid example and i can easily avoid using the for loop, but i want to actually later use parameters.

Thanks, and sorry if it is just too basic.

Comment: A related question on [module instantiation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20066850/97073).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verilog modules are not intended to be instantiated inside of initial or always blocks. If you want to instantiate multiple modules with a loop, then the `generate` block is what you want to use. Using your example:

```
module ands (
    input1,
    input2,
    outputs
);
    input [2:0] input1;
    input input2;
    output [2:0] outputs;

    integer itr;

    and a (outputs[0],input1[0],input2);

    genvar itr;
    generate
        for (itr = 1 ; itr <= 2; itr = itr+1)
            and a(outputs[itr],input1[itr],outputs[itr-1]);
    endgenerate

endmodule
```

This requires using verilog2001 or later.

Comment: Should the `integer itr;` not be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use genvar itr and a generate ... endgenerate block instead of an initial block.  This should do exactly what you want.