# Submodules in Verilog

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, you can create a module simply with the module syntax. How do you create multiple modules and call one from the other?

I have the following module that is my main module:

```
module Lab7Part1(SW, HEX0, HEX1, HEX2, HEX3);
        input  [15:0] SW;
        output [7:0] HEX0;
        output [7:0] HEX1;
        output [7:0] HEX2;
        output [7:0] HEX3;

        reg [7:0] OUTT;

        reg [7:0] ONE    = 8'b1001111;

        //SingleConverter sin_1(SW[3:0],   HEX0);
        //SingleConverter sin_2(SW[7:4],   HEX1);
        //SingleConverter sin_3(SW[11:8],  HEX2);
        //SingleConverter sin_4(SW[15:12], HEX3);
endmodule
```

and the following 'submodule' that I wish to 'call' in the main module:

```
module SingleConverter(SW, HEX);
    input  SW;
    output HEX;

    reg [7:0] OUT;

    reg [7:0] ZERO   = 8'b1000000;
    reg [7:0] ONE    = 8'b1001111;
    reg [7:0] TWO    = 8'b0100100;
    reg [7:0] THREE  = 8'b0110000;
    reg [7:0] FOUR   = 8'b0011001;
    reg [7:0] FIVE   = 8'b0010010;
    reg [7:0] SIX    = 8'b0000010;
    reg [7:0] SEVEN  = 8'b1111000;
    reg [7:0] EIGHT  = 8'b0000000;
    reg [7:0] NINE   = 8'b0011000;
    reg [7:0] DC     = 8'b1111111;

    always@(1'b0==1'b0)
    begin
        // SW
        if (SW == 4'b0000)
        begin
        // 0
            OUT[7:0] = ZERO;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0001)
        begin
        // 1
            OUT[7:0] = ONE;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0010)
        begin
        //2
            OUT[7:0] = TWO;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0011)
        begin
        // 3
            OUT[7:0] = THREE;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0100)
        begin
        // 4
            OUT[7:0] = FOUR;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0101)
        begin
        //5
            OUT[7:0] = FIVE;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0110)
        begin
        // 6
            OUT[7:0] = SIX;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b0111)
        begin
        // 7
            OUT[7:0] = SEVEN;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b1000)
        begin
        //8
            OUT[7:0] = EIGHT;
        end
        if (SW == 4'b1001)
        begin
        // 9
            OUT[7:0] = NINE;
        end
        if (SW > 4'b1001)
        begin
        // dc
            OUT[7:0] = DC;
        end
    end

    assign HEX = OUT;

endmodule
```

Comment: This is similar to [Verilog: How to instantiate a module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20066850/97073).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already placed 4 instances of SingleConverter in your top module; all you need to do is un-comment them.

Then, in SingleConverter you need to change:

```
input  SW;
output HEX;
```

to:

```
input  [3:0] SW;
output [7:0] HEX;
```

This looks strange:

```
always@(1'b0==1'b0)
```

You probably want:

```
always @*
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a module as a small chip with pins: there will be input pins and output pins.
When you use a module inside another one, you are not "calling" them, but you are instantiating it. It's like placing a chip (inner module) inside a larger PCB (your outer module), and connect pins from your chip to other points in your PCB.

That PCB in turn can be placed inside another one, so making a hierachy of modules, just like larger circuit modules are composed of several smaller modules/components.

Imagine you are designing a chip using a CAD system. Using a module inside another one is like using copy/paste to place a piece of circuit inside another, larger, one.

BTW: "call" is referred to programming languages that execute senteces, but here you are using a language to design a circuit.

Comment: So is there a way to create a module inside another or do you have to simple copy and paste code to use it together?

Comment: You can use a module inside another one. If you use a module several times inside another one, you are actually replicating it.