# How to make connection between wire signal of top module and inout signal of other module

Tags: verilog

The code is as follows:

```
module abc(a,b,c...);
  inout [15:0] a;
endmodule

module top;
   wire [15:0] data_a;
endmodule
```

How to make connection between wire signal data_a of top module and inout signal a of other module so that any change in data_a is reflected in inout port?

Comment: @Morgran the link does not show how to instantiate modules with inout ports. My answer does, and the question refers specifically to such case.

Comment: @ygoncho, Your answer only directly addresses the inout port by saying they "are not different". The main problem the OP seems to face was knowing how instantiate the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quite a detailed answer on [how to instantiate module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066851/97073), which shows how to make connections between modules.

Inouts are no different, instantiate the module and connect the wire inside `top`.

```
module abc(a,b,c...);
  inout [15:0] a;
endmodule

module top;
   wire [15:0] data_a;
   abc u_abs(            //module instance
     .a( data_a )        //port connections
   );
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Inout ports in this essence are not different from output ports or input ports. You can connect the inout port directly to the wire when you instantiate the module.

in the top module, after declaring your data_a wire, write:

```
abc abc_inst (
...
.a(data_a)
);
```