# Is it written in VHDL or Verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl

I am new to HDL and just wanted to confirm whether these lines of code are written in VHDL or Verilog?

```
DE0_SOPC DE0_SOPC_inst(
                        // 1) global signals:
                         .clk(CLOCK_50),
                         .pll_cpu(),
                         .pll_sdram(DRAM_CLK),
                         .reset_n(system_reset_n));
```

Comment: A bit short to make a real guess, and I have only briefly touched VHDL, but this doesn't look like it.

Comment: I think its Verilog. See [this question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module).

Comment: The file name it is contained in might have a clue, Verilog tends to end with a `*.v`

Comment: yes, it ends with .v extension. What extension is used for VHDL files then? thank you

Comment: The file extension used for VHDL files is usually `.vhd` or `.vhdl`. But, it is not a requirement.

Comment: The `//` comment is a dead giveaway. Verilog is based on C syntax; VHDL is based on Ada (VHDL comments are `--`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. These are verilog code lines. As per your previous comments, Type: .v files belong to verilog codes.

Answer (score 2):

It's Verilog. It is an instantiation of a module inside another. This is how you do it in Verilog; it is not how you do it in VHDL.