# Verilog State Machine with Pulse Counter

Tags: verilog

Hey guys so I written two Verilog modules, one is a state machine and the other is a counter that generates a pulse every half second for the machine to count.I tried to make a a top level design that would instantiate both modules, however when running a test bench, my state outputs would always equal to 'xx'. Any advice or help please?

COUNTER/PULSE:

```
module pulseit(clk, reset, pulse);
input clk, reset;
output pulse;
reg [25:0] count;
wire pulse;
always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset) count <= 26'b0; else
    if (pulse) count <= 26'b0; else
              count <= count + 26'b1;            
endmodule
```

STATE MACHINE:

```
module sm(clk, reset, in, state, pulse);
input   clk, reset, in, pulse;
output  [1:0] state;
reg     [1:0] state, nstate;

always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset) state <= 2'b0;
    else state <= nstate;

always @ (*)
    begin
    nstate = state;
    if (pulse)
        begin
        case(state)
            2'b00: nstate = (in)? 2'b01:2'b11;
            2'b01: nstate = (in)? 2'b10:2'b00;
            2'b10: nstate = (in)? 2'b11:2'b01;
            2'b11: nstate = (in)? 2'b00:2'b10;
        endcase
    end
end
endmodule
```

TOPLEVEL:

```
module topLevel(clk, rst, in, state);
input clk, rst, in;
output [1:0] state;
reg [1:0] state;

wire y;

pulseit pull (.clk(clk), .reset(rst), .pulse(y));

sm machine (.clk(clk), .reset(rst), .in(in), .state(state), .pulse(y));

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing a module, it is a good practice for designer to ensure that **all the ports must be driven from module**. There may be intentional some left-outs of connection, but the major ports must be connected.

Here wire `y` is connected as an output `pulse` of `pulseit` module. But the output `pulse` is never driven. The `pulseit` module just increments `count` and that too it is dependent on `pulse` signal. Also the **FSM module entirely depends on the `pulse` signal it gets as an input**.

`pulse` **needs to be driven by some logic inside `pulseit` module**. I modified the `pulseit` module as follows and it works fine now:

```
module pulseit(clk, reset, pulse);
input clk, reset;
output pulse;
reg [25:0] count;
wire pulse;
always @ (posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset) count <= 26'b0; else
    if (pulse) count <= 26'b0; else
              count <= count + 26'b1;            

// Let's say pulse goes HIGH when 26th bit of count goes HIGH.
assign pulse = count[25]; // NEED TO DRIVE PULSE 
endmodule
```

I have created a testbench for the above design at [EDAPlayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2L9C) for your reference. Some basic info about Verilog/SV modules can be found at [this link](http://verilog.renerta.com/mobile/source/vrg00027.htm) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module).

Note : When assigning,  Array index must be in range of index to not overflow.