# How to have individual bit values be labeled as inputs in modules to be used in other modules?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to make a module which XORs 5 bits of a 24-bit input, and when I try to reference the `XOR` module in my top module, I am getting an error when I try and assign the data bits I want to. I am not entirely sure what syntax I am supposed to use instead.  If I could get some advice on that, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
module XOR(input Data[0], input Data[1], input Data[2], input Data[3], input Data[4],  output Out);
    input [4:0] Data;
    output Out;
    
    assign Out = Data[0] ^ Data[1] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3] ^ Data[4];
endmodule

module twobit(
    input [24:0] Data,
    output [24:0] Errors
    );  
    
    wire [4:0] xorOut;
    XOR u1 (.Data[0](Data[0]), .Data[1](Data[1]), .Data[2](Data[2]), .Data[3](Data[3]), .Data[4](1), .Out(xorOut[0]));
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main problems with your code.

You use the wrong syntax for your `XOR` module port declarations.  You just need to use declarations similar to the `twobit` module.

The other problem is with the `XOR` port connections in the `twobit` module.

This code compiles without syntax errors:

```
module XOR(
    input [4:0] Data,
    output Out
);
    
    assign Out = Data[0] ^ Data[1] ^ Data[2] ^ Data[3] ^ Data[4];
endmodule

module twobit(
    input [24:0] Data,
    output [24:0] Errors
    );  
    
    wire [4:0] xorOut;
    XOR u1 (.Data(Data[4:0]), .Out(xorOut[0]));
    
endmodule
```

Here is a related post which may help explain this: [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)