# How to connect module to module in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, quartus, intel-fpga

I am a beginner in the development of FPGA. I am interested in how to correctly combine several modules in the top-level file.

For example: in the top-level file, I want to connect the output of module 1 to the input of module 2, and so on.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

I am trying to create a counter from 0 to 9 that outputs a number to a seven segment display. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or what could be improved.

Here is my code:

**File "seven_segment" (top level):**

```
module seven_segment (
    input CLK,
    output [6:0] out
);

counter counter ( .CLK(CLK));
bcd bcd ( .out(out));

endmodule
```

**File "bcd":**

```
module bcd (
    input [3:0] in,
    output reg [6:0] out
);

always @ (in) begin
    case (in)
        4'b0000 : out = 7'b1111110;
        4'b0001 : out = 7'b0110000;
        4'b0010 : out = 7'b1101101;
        4'b0011 : out = 7'b1111001;
        4'b0100 : out = 7'b0110011;
        4'b0101 : out = 7'b1111011;
        4'b0110 : out = 7'b1011111;
        4'b0111 : out = 7'b1010000;
        4'b1000 : out = 7'b1111111;
        4'b1001 : out = 7'b1111011;
        default : out = 7'b0000000;
    endcase

    end
endmodule
```

**File "counter":**

```
module counter (
    input CLK,
    output reg [3:0] count
);

always @ (posedge CLK)
begin
    if (count == 4'b1010)
        count <= 0;
    else
        count <= count + 1;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top module, you need to add a `wire` for the signal that you want to connect to both module instances.  Then you need to add port connections for that signal to each instance.  Here are the specific changes:

```
module seven_segment (
    input CLK,
    output [6:0] out
);

wire [3:0] count;
counter counter ( .CLK(CLK) , .count(count) );
bcd     bcd     ( .in(count), .out(out)     );

endmodule
```

You can give the wire any name that you want.  I chose to name it the same as the counter output (`count`), but as you can see, it is not a requirement to match the port name (`.in(count)`).

There are more examples in: [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066850/verilog-how-to-instantiate-a-module)